# Loading socket.io lobrary on front end

Tags: socket.io, frontend, client-side

I am trying to learn how to use socket.io and in the tutorial I am doing, they load socket.io on the front end by inserting the following script from cdnjs

```
script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.2/socket.io.min.js')
```

(Note: It seems that the newest is 2.2.0 and available on https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io)

***However,*** I don't see the link to this library through cdnjs on the socket.io website. If I am understanding the [socket.io client-side documentation correctly](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/), the documentation shows setting up the library by doing the following:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
const socket = io('http://localhost');
</script>

const io = require('socket.io-client');
// or with import syntax
import io from 'socket.io-client';
```

Basically, are these two different ways to load the library on the client side and is there a difference? It seems weird to insert the script from cdnjs when it doesn't seem to be on the socket.io website.

Comment: copy the socket.io.js from socket.io to your local directory, and reference it locally, e.g. src="scripts/socket.io.js" so that it can be run even without network connection.